# Aligning rotated text in minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, titles, minipage, rotating

I want to top align the text in the rotated `minipage`. I've tried different combinations of `\hfill` and `vfill` inside the first `minipage`, but none seem to work.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, headinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext} \linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}

\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \noindent\colorbox{mturkis}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.99\textheight]{0.09\textwidth}
        \centering\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries\LARGE\color{white}\scshape\lsstyle bachelorarbeit}
    \end{minipage}}\hspace{25pt}%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.99\textheight]{0.75\textwidth}
        \RaggedRight
        \vspace{40pt}

        \LARGE\textls{\linespread{1.1}\textsc{really super long title\\of my super really long thesis\\with four\\lines}}\\

        \vfill

        \normalsize
        \textit{von}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape\color{mblau}name}\\[5pt]
        \href{mailto:something@mail.de}{\url{something@mail.de}}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{am}\\[15pt]
        \textit{datum}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{akademische Betreuung durch}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape prof.\,dr.-ing. name}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape faculty}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape university}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{externe Betreuung durch}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape name}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape company}\\

        \vspace{40pt}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the color and typesetting of the page. I like the page template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the rotated contents in a box of width slightly less than `\textheight` and right aligned:
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, headinclude]{scrbook}

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, headinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext} \linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{mblau}{RGB}{10, 59, 104}
    \definecolor{mturkis}{RGB}{0, 171, 183}

\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \noindent\colorbox{mturkis}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.99\textheight]{0.09\textwidth}
        \centering\rotatebox{90}{\makebox[0.88\textheight][r]{\bfseries\LARGE\color{white}\scshape\lsstyle bachelorarbeit}}
    \end{minipage}}\hspace{25pt}%
    \begin{minipage}[c][0.99\textheight]{0.75\textwidth}
        \RaggedRight
        \vspace{40pt}

        \LARGE\textls{\linespread{1.1}\textsc{really super long title\\of my super really long thesis\\with four\\lines}}\\

        \vfill

        \normalsize
        \textit{von}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape\color{mblau}name}\\[5pt]
        \href{mailto:something@mail.de}{\url{something@mail.de}}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{am}\\[15pt]
        \textit{datum}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{akademische Betreuung durch}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape prof.\,dr.-ing. name}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape faculty}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape university}\\

        \vfill

        \textit{externe Betreuung durch}\\[15pt]
        \textls{\scshape name}\\[5pt]
        \textls{\scshape company}\\

        \vspace{40pt}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sebastiano: A copy-paste accident again…Thank you for warning me!